# Use lxml to parsing Multiple xml files in different folder

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I am trying to parse multiple XML files from different folders with lxml. I am using **os.walk()** and **fnmatch.filter()** to find the xml file from, for example ,Folder name *testlog* . and In this folder , there are more subfolder and in every single one of them there are xml file with name *result.xml* . And I am trying to parse these xml files and generate PDF for every *result.xml*  using Reportlab. And my code for parsing is:

```
import os
from lxml import etree
import fnmatch

path = 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/testlog'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for files in fnmatch.filter(files, 'result.xml'):
#       print files   
        tree = etree.parse(files)
```

And if i print the file , i can get all the *result.xml* files listed but if i'm trying to parse,i get the following Error:

```
IOError: Error reading file 'result.xml' : failed to load external entity "result.xml"
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

files is just the name of the file; root is the path to the directory it is in.  You need to combine the two (say, using os.path.join) to open that specific file.

Comment: I've joined them sucessfully but when I try to parse I get this: "  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'endswith'
". Any ideas?

Comment: You don't appear to be the author of this question; what code are you running?

Comment: `directory = os.getcwd()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
 for file in files:
         if (file.endswith('.xml')):
          with open('test.txt', 'a') as txt:
           
           doc = os.path.join(os.sep, root, file)
           
           doc = str(doc)


           tree = ET.parse(doc)
           root = tree.getroot()` 

if I print out doc, it shows the full path, but not getting anywhere. The code works fine when the program is in the same folder as the xml files, but when in directories it fails.

Comment: Try `os.path.join(root, file)`.

Comment: Post as an actual question with code one could actually read.